# Swift Framework not loaded

Tags: frameworks, swift, ios8, rpath

I recently completed an API Client to be used with my Swift app. I wrote the framework in a separate project, and then added the subproject to my main project, similarly to how the framework for [Quick](https://github.com/Quick/Quick) and [Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble) is added to a project.

When I try to run my app, I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/MyAPIClient.framework/MyAPIClient
Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8DA25606-407B-4B13-8147-F3B18C06031E/MyApp.app/MyApp
Reason: image not found
```

and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to solve this error.

My `.xcodeproj` is not added to the same directory as my main project, but appears to be symbolically linked.

Does anyone know what's happening?

**EDIT:**
I've tried adding the project as a `git submodule` within a directory, and I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by adding a "Copy Files" build phase to my main application target, in which I copy the `MyAPIClient.framework` into my application bundle into the `Frameworks` directory.

Hopefully this helps some of you all out as well.